# Is history.replaceState a right tool to sync changes to URL after search string update

Tags: javascript

I know this question a bit subjective, but still. Everytime a user types in new chars into input and runs a search I need to synchronize the new search state to the URL. So I can use either `history.replaceState` or `history.search` for that:

```
input.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
   const searchString = event.current.value;
   history.replaceState(..., searchString);
});
```

or

```
input.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
   const searchString = event.current.value;
   history.search = searchString;
});
```

`history.search` reloads the page though. Any other approach I'm missing? Maybe `history.pushState` is more applicable?

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: yeah, thanks, I considered `push` state, but I don't really want to add entries to history because it's not like a user is navigating anywhere